# customizing biblatex / authoryear: labels in bibliography and format of editor

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to customize biblatex such that all requirements of my university are met. I use authortitle as bibstyle and authoryear as citestyle. My language is French. I made already some changes, see the code sample. There are however to changes that I cannot figure out how to make. Maybe I can find some help here. The bibliography entries should for example look like this:

(Impey--MacGregor 1985) Impey, O. et MacGregor, A. (dir.), The origins of museums: the cabinet of curiosities in the sixteenth- and seventeenth century Europe, Oxford, Clarendon Press, 1985

The following changes are missing:

1. When I cite a source in the text (I basically only use articles and books), the format is: (Impey--MacGregor 1985), which I generate with \parencite{}. I want that this label (with the round brackets) also appears at the beginning of the corresponding entry in the bibliography.
2. It happens that at some sources the authors are editors at the same time. In those cases I want to write a (dir.) behind the last author name, as in the upper example, instead of the automatic "sous la direction de ...", which would mention the same names one more time.

In the example I have shown I used the following source:

```
@book{im85,
author = {Impey, O. and MacGregor, A.},
title = {The origins of museums: the cabinet of curiosities in sixteenth- and senventeenth century Europe},
editor = {Impey, O. and MacGregor, A.},
year = {1985},
volume = {},
publisher = {Oxford, Clarendon Press},
pages = {},
isbn = {},
keywords = {bibliographie}
}
```

and this is my file:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,bottom=2.8cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes} % french quotation marks in the bibliography
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
bibstyle=authortitle,
citestyle=authoryear,
babel = hyphen
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibli}

% The following block of code makes names separated by "--" in the citations
\let\oldmultinamedelim\multinamedelim
\let\oldfinalnamedelim\finalnamedelim
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{--}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{--}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\oldmultinamedelim}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\oldfinalnamedelim}%
}

% Changes the point after the author name to a comma
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% Normally in French the authors appear in small capitals when cited. The following command prevents this.
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

% Last name first, then first name
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}

\begin{document}
\title[Projet de thèse]{Titre du projet}
\author{Nom de l'auteur}
\maketitle

On a lu \parencite{im85}.

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword={source}, heading=subbibliography, title={Sources}]
\printbibliography[keyword={bibliographie}, heading=subbibliography, title={Bibliographie}]

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Good question style with minimal working code. (+1)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You would probably be interested in [`biblatex-ext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext).

Comment: Re point 2: I think it is extremely rare to have a case where one person is both author and editor and should be credited as such. In the example I think we are looking at a `@collection` and Impey, O. and MacGregor, A. are only editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For issue no. 1 you can use [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) and its `introcite=plain` option.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
bibstyle = ext-authortitle,
citestyle = ext-authoryear,
introcite=plain,
autolang = hyphen
]{biblatex}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{im85,
  title     = {The Origins of Museums},
  subtitle  = {The Cabinet of Curiosities in Sixteenth- and Senventeenth-Century {Europe}},
  editor    = {Impey, Oliver and MacGregor, Arthur},
  year      = {1985},
  location  = {Oxford},
  publisher = {Clarendon Press},
  keywords  = {bibliographie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\addspace}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{--}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}% sortname is probably what you want, updated to new (>=v3.3) name format 

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\locpubdelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}
On a lu \parencite{im85}.

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword={source}, heading=subbibliography, title={Sources}]
\printbibliography[keyword={bibliographie}, heading=subbibliography, title={Bibliographie}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Re your second issue: I think it is going to be very rare that you have a work where the same list of people is author and editor and where you would want to conflate the two such that only the editors remain.

In the case at hand a bit of googling seems to suggest to me that Messrs Impey and MavGregor need not be listed as `author`s at all. They are editors of the entire volume, but not the authors. So the correct input seems to be (note `@collection` for a collection of works by different authors instead of `@book` for a book written in its entirety by the same set of authors)

```
@collection{im85,
  title     = {The Origins of Museums},
  subtitle  = {The Cabinet of Curiosities in Sixteenth- and Senventeenth-Century {Europe}},
  editor    = {Impey, Oliver and MacGregor, Arthur},
  year      = {1985},
  location  = {Oxford},
  publisher = {Clarendon Press},
  keywords  = {bibliographie},
}
```

---

*Edited for name changes in v0.4 of `biblatex-ext`.*

Comment: Hi Moewe, I tested your solution and it works perfectly. Thank you! This is a really great community where you get really good advice.

Comment: Your point, that Impey and MacGregor are actually only editors, is also good and justified. I guess I mainly had it like that so that their names appear in the citation. But you fixed this, too!