# Text-citation at start of bibliography entry (BibLaTeX)

Tags: biblatex

I would like to start my bibliography entries with the text-style citation.

I have the bib file `mybib.bib`

```
@article{art1,
author = {Foster, Joe and Burton, Nathan and Cook, Andrew},
journal = {Journal 1},
pages = {1-10},
title = {{Title 1}},
volume = {1},
year = {2018}
}
```

Using `\citet{art1}` I get *Foster et al. (2018)*, as desired. I would like the formatted reference in the bibliography to start with *(Foster et al. (2018))*, i.e.,

> (Foster et al. (2018)) Joe Foster, Nathan Burton, and Andrew Cook. Title 1. Journal 1, 1:1-10, 2018.

I have tried using the `biblatex` package in combination with `authoryear`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,dashed=false,doi,url]{biblatex}
\begin{document}    
Citation 1: \citet{art1}
\printbibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have a look at my [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) style bundle. You'll be interested in `introcite`, the documentation has a few examples and there are also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433643/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420595/35864.

Comment: If `biblatex-ext` works for you, feel free to post an answer with the working code (self-answers are actively encouraged here). If you have problems, just edit your question with what you have tried and why and how it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 3):

`introcite` from `biblatex-ext` did the job! See below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, natbib=true, citestyle=ext-authoryear, bibstyle=ext-authortitle, introcite=plain, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family} % given-family format

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}} % introcite in bold face and between parentheses
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\addspace} % remove colon between introcite and authors


\begin{document}
\citep{art1}

\citep{art2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`mybib.bib`

```
@article{art1,
author = {Foster, Joe and Burton, Nathan},
journal = {First journal},
pages = {1-10},
title = {{First Title}},
volume = {1},
number = {10},
month = {1},
year = {2018},
}
@inproceedings{art2,
author = {Foster, Joe and Burton, Nathan and Cook, Andrew},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2nd Conference},
pages = {11-20},
title = {{Second Title}},
year = {2018},
month = {12},
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have taken the liberty of adding a picture of the output. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Note that you may want to add an explicit `sorting=nyt` to sort your references by name-year-title instead of name-title-year. The sorting is controlled by the `.bbx` file. `authortitle` and by extension also `ext-authortitle` set `sorting=nty` (or rather don't change the default `sorting=nty`). But `authoryear` works better with `sorting=nyt`. Note also that you can use `date = {2017-11}` instead of `year = {2017}, month = {11},` with `biblatex`. Furthermore or consider it bad form to double brace title fields for no reason.